# Ping can connect internet using IPs or NS; browers can't contact anything, including router using IP

Tags: windows-7, router, internet, routing

I'm using Windows7 with SP1. The CPU is an i5 3450.

When the problem started my wife decided to have all of our computers have user login and passwords.  Also I believe she tried setting the wireless access to be on a schedule by setting up the router (I showed her how to connect to the router page so she could turn off wireless).

All computers and devices lost connection to the internet and router/modem. I did a full modem reset and was able to get back internet access to all computers but mine.

As the title says I can ping anything, but FF and IE both can not bring up anything including the modem/router using IPs.

Comment: did you check your dns settings? try `8.8.8.8` or `4.4.4.4`

Comment: @angs how would that make a difference if the OP is using IPs?

Comment: @terdon: OP says he can ping IPs but the web browsers cannot show the contents. It sounded like a DNS problem, or am I wrong?

Comment: @terdon: I can ping both IP's and names. Both resolve so the DNS resolves. Before this happened I was using OpenDNS, but I've gone back to the ISP's dns and turned off all anti's

Comment: one of my attemtps to fix this has been a rollback to before all these problems and purge of local dns cache

Comment: @angs no, if it a DNS problem, then neither the browsers nor ping will be able to resolve hostnames. In any case, if it does not work when using IPs, it is not a DNS issue.

Comment: Are you using any proxy servers? Can you connect to ftp sites with an ftp client? What if you install a new browser, does that have the same problem? I am trying to determine if it is a global problem or specific to your installed browsers.

Comment: No proxy, no fpt client loaded, but suspect it works as updates are happening for MS, AVG, Steam, ect.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try running cmd and execute telnet www.google.com 80 then GET /

   - if you get any google content returned then install other browser using usb

   ## ->

   - can you access any ftp places try ftp://ftp.sunet.se

   ## ->

   - if you got any 3d party firewall check settings

   ## ->

   - Try to close any antivirus software and reboot

   ## ->

   - Check if IP have been set manually

Comment: HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 925
Date: Fri, 05 Jul 2013 04:22:47 GMT
Server: GFE/2.0

<!DOCTYPE html>
               <html lang=en>
                               <meta charset=utf-8>
                                                     <meta name=viewport content
="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
                                                          <title>Error 400 (Bad
Request)!!1</title>
                     <style>
                                *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px ar
ial,sans-serif}

Comment: plus some more from the telnet request.  trying to get a clean install for a browser, but it seems my computer is sending bad data? How do I check if IP's have been set manually?

Comment: Link: http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-manually-assign-an-ip-address-in-windows-7.html but your internet works download teamviewer on usb and send me id + password for remote support to sm92mual@hotmail.com